# How to identity header and its sub-headers from the pdf using Azure Document intelligence Layout model?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am using azure document Intelligence layout model to extract the information from the pdf. I am using python sdk to call the API and extracting the relevant information from the json output. Extracted information I am writing in the csv file as one column becomes header and second column is the section of the respective header.

I can identify the headers from the
role key of paragraphs collection using JSON ouput where model gives as Sectionheading.

However,I am not sure how I can differentiate between the headers and its subheaders so I can combine headers and its subheders together

Thanks in advance
.

Comment: @Niranjanp please the things/code you tried

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.